# How to add action hook for whmcs order

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I just noticed that ns1 and ns2 columns in tblhosting are blank. can someone give me code which will add ns in databases, once the order is accepted? For 2 services I am using different nameservers.

shared:

```
ns1.shared.com

ns2.shared.com
```

for reseller.

```
ns1.reseller.com

ns2.reseller.com
```

I hope I will get some assistance with it. thanks in advance.

I am trying to build hook something like this,

```
function ns($vars){
if ($vars['groupname'] == "Shared Hosting") {
    $groupname = $vars['groupname'].
    return array("groupname" => $groupname);
}
```

and then sql query. but not sure how to add sql query here.

I am expecting an entry in tblhosting >> ns1 & ns2 columns. 
Using `UPDATE` via sql query. but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

- One solution is to create Server Module.
  [Server Modules](https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/)
- Implement the *_CreateAccount* method.
- Configure your product to use this module.

  [image: Cofigure Product]
- Put the following code in file:

> \modules\servers\test\test.php

---

```
<?php
// if(!defined("WHMCS"))exit("This file cannot be accessed directly");
// see: https://developers.whmcs.com/domain-registrars/function-index/
// see: https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/supported-functions/
// See: https://github.com/WHMCS/sample-provisioning-module/blob/master/modules/servers/provisioningmodule/provisioningmodule.php L443
// "Create", "Suspend","Unsuspend", "Terminate"
require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/dbfunctions.php');
require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/functions.php');
require_once(ROOTDIR . '/includes/clientfunctions.php');

function test_MetaData()
{
    return array("DisplayName"=>"Test Module","APIVersion"=>"1.0","RequiresServer"=>true);
}

function test_CreateAccount($params)
{
    $serviceid=$params['serviceid'];
    $my_ns1="ns1.shared.com";
    $my_ns2="ns2.shared.com";
    $qr=update_query('tblhosting',array("ns1"=>$my_ns1,"ns2"=>$my_ns2),array('id' => $serviceid));
    if(!$qr) throw new Exception("Cannot Update data");
    return "success";
}

?>
```

**-------- UPDATE 1 ------------**

If you want to create hook for 'AcceptOrder',put your code in file:

> \includes\hooks\test_hook.php

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
add_hook('AcceptOrder', 1, function($vars) {
    $orderid=$vars['orderid'];
    $my_packageid=10; //hardCoded
    $my_ns1="ns1.shared.com";
    $my_ns2="ns2.shared.com";

    $res=Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('orderid',$orderid)->get();
    foreach($res as $row)
    {
        if($row->packageid==$my_packageid)
        {
            $up=Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('id',$row->id)->update(['ns1'=>$my_ns1,'ns2'=>$my_ns2]);
        }
    }

});
?>
```

But you must set the product ID hardcoded // 10 in this Example.

**-------- UPDATE 2 ------------**

to user Group, you must make Joins between many tables ..

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
    add_hook('AcceptOrder',1,function($vars){
        $orderid=$vars['orderid'];
        $my_packageid=10; //hardCoded
        $my_gid=1; //hardCoded
        $my_ns1="ns1.shared.com";
        $my_ns2="ns2.shared.com";
        //$res=Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('orderid',$orderid)->get();
        $res=Capsule::select("SELECT packageid , gid ,tblhosting.id AS hostingid ,tblhosting.orderid FROM tblhosting INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblhosting.packageid=tblproducts.id LEFT OUTER JOIN tblproductgroups ON tblproducts.gid=tblproductgroups.id WHERE tblhosting.orderid={$orderid}");
        foreach($res as $row)
        {
            if($row->gid==$my_gid)
            {
                $up=Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('id',$row->hostingid)->update(['ns1'=>$my_ns1,'ns2'=>$my_ns2]);
            }
        }

});
?>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the code. But when I set test module in whmcs. I am getting error this module is not supported. Can you tell me how to merge ns part in existing cpanel? On thlink you can decoded version if you want to see actual code.

Comment: https://github.com/WHMCSCare/WHMCS-7.8.0-decoded/blob/master/modules/servers/cpanel/cpanel.php

Comment: Thanks for you; I have tested on WHMCS 7 .. I have updated the answer to use hook.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats work perfectly! is ot possible to use if code for pacakge id? I have 3 packages : 22,23,24. For these 3 pacakges I want to set same NS.

Comment: OR is it possible to use group ID? From shared hosting group id is : 1

Comment: Ja .. you can use if statment, also you can do it by group id .. see Update 2

Answer (score 0):

tblhosting ns1 + ns2 fields are used for server type products, e.g. VPS. If configured correctly they should contain the values entered when ordering the service

For domains, the nameservers are saved in the tblorders table (nameservers field).